# Serverless throws "Can't Find Module" Error on all imported modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

Does anyone know why when using Serverless for AWS Lambda, I get a module not found error even though the module is in the correct place?

When trying to deploy the API onto AWS Lamdba  using serverless deploy - serverless throws errors complaining it can't find modules which are imported by the import statements.

In my specific case its resolvers and typeDefs.

[image]

Is there a way to get serverless to recognise imports?

Comment: did the modules get deployed to the lambda as well or are they in a lambda layer by chance? (i.e. you ran `npm install` before running `serverless deploy`?)

Comment: IS there a way to check that the modules got deployed to the lambda server ? I am not sure.

Comment: When you navigate to the lambda in aws console do you see a modules folder? or only your entry file (probably like index.js or whatever you named it)

Comment: Where can you see the folders that have been uploaded ? (Sorry total first time using AWS)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-console.html

Comment: My code editor isn't showing up because it says "Code too large to enable editing" - is there any other way to see what files are there ?

Comment: Your build process needs to bundle all dependencies required or do some form of tree shaking

Comment: You would be better using a lambda layer to store the node modules and link it to your lamda function. https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/layers

Comment: I can't even get a simple query to run LOCALLY using: serverless invoke local -f graphql -p query.json - does serverless not understand import statements at all ?